# use conditional type in typescript interface key iteration

Tags: typescript

Hi have 2 interfaces and a type

```js
interface A {
    k1: string
    k2: string
}

interface B {
    k3: string
    k4: A
}

type Error = { key:string, value:string}
```

I have developed a declaration that creates an interface with all the keys of a given interface and the `type = Error[]`

```js
type AutoErrors<P> = { 
    [K in keyof P]-?: Error[] 
}
```

That works well since `AutoErrors<A>` gives

```js
{
  k1: Error[]
  k2: Error[]
}
```

But now I would like it to be recursive, ie , if the parameter type key is not of type string I would like its type to be `AutoErrors<T>`

For example `AutoErrors<B>` should be

```js
{
  k3: Error[],
  k4: AutoErrors<A>
}
```

I have tried

```js
type AutoErrors<X> = {
  [K in keyof X]-?: X[K] extends string ? Error[] : AutoErrors<X[K]>;
};
```

but it is not working well , as if the test X[K] extends string is not well interpreted

Comment: "I have tried but it is not working well"... what, specifically, have you tried?

Comment: sorry I fixed the typo

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using?  What's not working well about it?

Comment: Your code above works in [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) so something else is going on.

Comment: you are absolutely right @jcalz, but I was seeing an error in VSCOde editor because I was trying with an interface containing only optional keys.For that I add to state X[K] extends string | undefined.  You definitely deserve the reward because your statement help me find what was going wrong , post the definitive version and I will vote for you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as posted in your question [works in the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=namespace%20ErrorHasAGlobalType%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20k1%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20k2%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20interface%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20k3%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20k4%3A%20A%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20type%20Error%20%3D%20%7B%20key%3A%20string%2C%20value%3A%20string%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20type%20AutoErrors%3CX%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20[K%20in%20keyof%20X]-%3F%3A%20X[K]%20extends%20string%20%3F%20Error[]%20%3A%20AutoErrors%3CX[K]%3E%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20type%20AutoErrorsA%20%3D%20AutoErrors%3CA%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20type%20AutoErrorsB%20%3D%20AutoErrors%3CB%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20declare%20const%20autoErrorsB%3A%20AutoErrorsB%3B%0D%0A%20%20autoErrorsB.k3[0].key%20%2F%2F%20okay%0D%0A%20%20autoErrorsB.k4.k1[0].value%20%2F%2F%20okay%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D), so I suspected that something else was going on.  As it turns out, the issue had to do with optional properties, such as

```
type UhOh = AutoErrors<{ a?: string }>; // becomes {a: string}, not good
```

The original `AutoErrors<>` definition didn't work in that case, because `string | undefined` does not extend `string`.  The fix for that, as you know, is to check for `string | undefined` instead of just `string`:

```
type AutoErrors<X> = {
  [K in keyof X]-?: X[K] extends string | undefined ?
  Error[] : AutoErrors<X[K]>
}
```

which works:

```
type Okay = AutoErrors<{ a?: string }>; // becomes {a: Error[]}, as expected
```

Glad you found out what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an approach similar to the one for [DeepReadOnly](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13923)

```
export type primitive = string | number | boolean | undefined | null
export type DeepError<T> = 
    T extends (infer U)[] ? Array<DeepErrorObject<U>> :
    T extends primitive ? Error[] : DeepErrorObject<T>;

export type DeepErrorObject<T> = {
readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepError<T[P]>
}
// sample usage
interface A {
    k1: string
    k2: string
} 
interface B {
    k3: string
    k4: A
    k4Arr: B[]
}
type Error = { 
    key:string, 
    message:string
}

type ErrorA = DeepError<B>
let d: ErrorA;
d.k4Arr[0].k3; // Error[]
```

Comment: The OP code should work for the stated purposes, so there's something else going on.

Comment: @jcalz Hm .. you are right, I didn't see the update, his code should work fine ..